# Programmatically colour row when specific cell contains 0

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a script that would turn a row green when the cell in column **K** contains `0`.

For example I would like **B5** through **L5** to turn green when **K5** has a `0`.

Conditional formatting is not sufficient because I have some rows that do not need to be formatted now but they might in the future.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you asking a question about a spreadsheet application. Or is this a html table?

Comment: it is a googe spreadsheet.

Comment: The solution would be more interesting if you specify other conditions, when apply color. Not only column K=0. For example, if you want to mark colored rows manually, you can insert additional column with checkboxes and still apply **conditional formatting**. Using onEdit trigger is convinient only for manual editing a cell or range.

Answer (score 1):

Behold the insanity! Had a bit of fun with this.

Open your sheet and select the range you would like to make green then in the menu go Row Magic | Set Target. You will be prompted to enter a name for that range.

Then go Row Magic | Attach on the field you want to watch for Zero. Enter the name of the range you want to update (the names of all the ranges are listed). Now enter zero in the field and the range will change to a green background! Theres a slight delay on my pc ~1 second.

This is my first app script so it most likely can be improved on a lot.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Row Magic')
  .addItem('Set Target', 'setTarget')
  .addItem('Attach', 'attachToRange')
  .addToUi();
}

function onEdit(e) {
  //var range = e.range;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // Returns the active cell
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var value = cell.getValue(); 
  var md = sheet.getDeveloperMetadata();

  md.forEach(function(m) {
    if (m.getKey().indexOf('rangeTarget_') === 0) {
      var keySplit = m.getKey().split('_');
      var row = keySplit[1];
      var column = keySplit[2];
      if (row == cell.getRow() && column == cell.getColumn()) {
        var rangeName = m.getValue();
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var ranges = ss.getNamedRanges();
        ranges[0].getName()
        ranges.forEach(function (r) { 
          if (r.getName() === rangeName) {
            if (value === 0) {
              r.getRange().setBackground('#00FF00');
            }
            else {
              r.getRange().setBackground('#FFFFFF');
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });

}

function setTarget() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Enter name', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
    ss.setNamedRange(response.getResponseText(), range)
  }  
}

function attachToRange() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // Returns the active cell
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();
  var rangeNames = [];
  namedRanges.forEach(function(r) {
    rangeNames.push(r.getName());
  });

  var response = ui.prompt('Enter range to target\n' + rangeNames.join('\n'), ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.OK) {
    var r = response.getResponseText();
    if (rangeNames.indexOf(r) > -1) {
      var row = cell.getRow();
      var column = cell.getColumn();
      sheet.addDeveloperMetadata('rangeTarget_'+row+'_'+column, r);
    }
  }
}
```